# Laravel Cashier show Exception message

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to show the error message after make a "charge" to stripe" but still showing the default error laravel page.

I'm trying to do a try catch to show the Exception in my template but i cant

This is my code

```
public function payment(ReloadRequest $request)
    {

         $result = Auth::user()->getStripeId();
             $amount = $request->amount;
         $token = $request->stripeToken;

  try {
         if(!$result) {


    $customer = Auth::user()->subscription()->createStripeCustomer($token, [
     'email' => Auth::user()->email
        ]);

    Auth::user()->setStripeId($customer->id);
     Auth::user()->save();

    }


          Auth::user()->updateCard($token);


     $response =Auth::user()->charge((floatval($amount)*100), [
    'receipt_email' => Auth::user()->email,
    'currency' => "pen",


    ]);
       }
        catch(Exception $e)
        {
           return $e;
        }
```

Comment: try `catch (\Exception $e)`

Comment: Dude, thank you so much! it works!

Comment: I've added an answer so that this question can be marked as resolved and no longer appear in unanswered lists.

Answer (score 3):

You need to specify

```
\Exception
```

This is because otherwise you're trying to catch Exceptions in your Controller namespace, likely

```
App\Http\Controllers\Exception
```

From http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.fallback.php

> Inside a namespace, when PHP encounters an unqualified Name in a class name, function or constant context, it resolves these with different priorities. Class names always resolve to the current namespace name. Thus to access internal or non-namespaced user classes, one must refer to them with their fully qualified Name as in:

```
<?php

namespace A\B\C;

class Exception extends \Exception {}

$a = new Exception('hi'); // $a is an object of class A\B\C\Exception
$b = new \Exception('hi'); // $b is an object of class Exception
```